# EPiServer 7 MVC IDisplayModes

Tags: episerver-7

Trying to setup a Mobile Channel for use in Edit Mode in EPiServer 7.

Been following this link

http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/7/Content/Display-Channels/

Created an Initialization module

```
[InitializableModule]
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
public class DisplayModesInitialization : IInitializableModule
{
    public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
    {
        if (context.HostType == HostType.WebApplication)
        {
            System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.RemoveAt(0);
            context.Locate.DisplayChannelService()
                                .RegisterDisplayMode(new DefaultDisplayMode(RenderingTags.Mobile)
                                {
                                    ContextCondition = (r) => r.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
                                });                
        }
    }

    public void Preload(string[] parameters) { }

    public void Uninitialize(EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationEngine context) { }
}
```

As you can see I tried removing the existing "Mobile" display mode that exists to be replaced with the one created through the EPiServer DisplayChannelService().

Just browsing to the homepage works ok but when I force the userAgent to be a mobile browser it does hit the correct view... i.e. `Index.mobile.cshtml`

However it appears to still be looking for the `_Layout.cshtml` instead of `_Layout.mobile.cshtml` and even at that it fails to find it.

```
The file "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.
```

Anyone successfully create a mobile `IDisplayMode` for MVC through the `EPiServer DisplayChannelService` ?

Also if I explicitly set the layout in the mobile view

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.mobile.cshtml";
}
```

If fails to find that also ?

```
The file "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.mobile.cshtml" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.
```

both the _Layout and _Layout.mobile DO exist in that location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

Discovered that _ViewStart.cshtml had the following set:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true; 
}
```

So I removed the `DisplayModeProvider.Instance.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true;` and it now works.

Not sure why this was causing the problem as there are both mobile and desktop views for the homepage and also mobile and desktop layouts ?